# Documentum 6.5 SP3 error with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, documentum6.5, dfc

I am getting this error while invoking *Documentum* in my application.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient
```

The application server is *Apache Tomcat*

We are upgrading from *Documentum 5.3 sp4* to *6.4 sp3*
Was able to make it work locally but not when deployed on the server (*Solaris*).

Answer (score 0):

Everytime when I faced similar problems, here's my debugging steps:

1. Is there any path hardcoded, or environment var pointing to the local location
2. Is there Java version on the Solaris same as the local version
3. Is the DfClient library found in the specific location

Comment: Checked all 3. Also put the dfc.jar within the WEB-INF/lib directory.

Comment: Can anyone please help here. This problem still persists.